# Determinant of identity matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'm trying to setup an algorithm that optimizes a system of equations as a $k \times k$ matrix approaches an identity matrix. Note that the elements of this matrix are bounded between $0$ and $1$. I can see how I could do this with a $2 \times 2$ matrix by running iterations until the determinant of my matrix equals $1$. I think this can be extended to $k \times k$ matrices, but I can't find anything that points me to a confirmation or rejection of this idea—nor am I smart enough to come up with a proof on my own. Any help to help me confirm or reject this idea would be most welcome!

Comment: Determinant of identity matrix of any size $n\times n$ is 1, if you're asking just this. <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Characterization_of_the_determinant>

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My question is if it is true that, when the elements of the matrix are bounded between 0 and 1, ONLY the identity matrix has a determinant of 1. If that is not the case, searching a solution to my problem using the determinant could lead to matrices other than the identity matrix (which is what I'd like to have).

Comment: If you just shift all 1's in identity matrix one position you'll get the matrix with 1 or -1 determinant depending on size. For example, matrix $\left(\begin{array}{l}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ has determinant 1

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{l}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ has determinant 1 for any $0\leq t \leq 1$.

Comment: $\left(
\begin{array}{lll}
1 &\frac{1}{2}& 1 \\ \frac{1}{5} & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{16}{1011} & \frac{193}{240} & \frac{115253}{121320}
\end{array}
\right)$ has determinant 1

Answer (score 1):

There are enough freedom for matrix elements to set determinant equal to 1.

For example, for $n=2$ matrix $A_2=\left(\begin{array}{l} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ has determinant 1 at any $0\leq t \leq 1$. The same for transposed matrix $A_2$.

For $n=3$ there are too many freedom to write common solution but there are many particular solutions having determinant 1, for example, $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 &\frac{1}{2}& 1 \\ \frac{1}{5} & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{16}{1011} & \frac{193}{240} & \frac{115253}{121320}
\end{array}
\right)$.